# Test styled-components with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, styled-components

I got a question about testing with enzyme, so basically what I'm doing is something that looks like:

```jsx
const BaseButton = styled.button`
  padding: 10px;
`;

const PrimaryButton = BaseButton.extend`
  color: red;
`;

const SecondaryButton = BaseButton.extend`
  color: blue;
`;

// My actual component:
const buttonTypes = {
    primary: PrimaryButton,
    secondary: SecondaryButton
};
export const Button = (props: Props) => {
    const { type = 'primary' } = props;
    const Btn = buttonTypes[type] || buttonTypes.primary;

    return (
        <Btn
            {...props}
            onClick={props.onClick}
        >
            {props.children}
        </Btn>
    );
};
```

I want to do some testing with Enzyme passing different props on `type`, for example a test should say something like:

`should render a Primary button if type='primary'`

`should render a Secondary button if type='secondary'`

`should render a Primary button if type=''`

`should render a Primary button by default`

My buttons have way more attributes but I just showed `color` for the sake of simplicity.

Any ideas on how can I achieve  that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

1. Adding a data attribute to the button
2. Mount the component using Enzyme
3. After mounting I used `component.html()` to get the component as a string
4. Check if the correct attribute was applied

```js
// Button.js
const buttons = {
    primary: 'primary',
    secondary: 'secondary'
};

export const ButtonStyles = styled.button.attrs({
    'data-button-type': props => buttons[props.type] || buttons.primary
})`
    padding: 10px;
`;

// Button.tests.js

it('should render a primary button when type prop is missing', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <Button
            {...defaultProps}
            type=""
        />
    );

    expect(wrapper.html().includes('data-button-type="primary"')).toBeTruthy();
});
```